# PYTHON: Simplest way to open a csv file and find the maximum number in a column and the name assosciated with it?

Tags: python, csv

I have looked at this reference so please do not refer me to it.

[Find max number in .CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552008/find-max-number-in-csv-file-in-python) I struggled to modify this code to my own document for over an hour with no results. The best I got from that code was printing out maximum value, and I got 0, which is incorrect. I need to 1) find the maximum value in column F, (38,332,521) and 2) print out the state associated with the maximum value (California).

Here is the csv I'm using: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29hT1HI-pwxMjBPQWFYaWoyalE

This is the code I've come up with myself, any help/feedback would be appreciated!

```
def largestState(): 
    INPUT  = "statepopulations.csv"
    COLUMN = 5   # 6th column

    with open(INPUT, "rU") as csvFile:
        theFile  = csv.reader(csvFile)
        header = next(theFile, None)    # skip header row
        pop = [float(row[COLUMN]) for row in theFile]

    max_pop = max(pop)
    print max_pop

largestState()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max` function should handle that for you. In my below code I've already "read" the CSV (*with fake data, but you seem to have a grasp on that portion*)

```
data = [
    ["California", 123456],
    ["Idaho", 123],
    ["Utah", 2]
]

print max(data, key=lambda _: _[1])
```

This yields `['California', 123456]`

The `key=lambda _: _[1]` tells the function to use the second value of each record, the population in this case, to check the maximum.

Putting it all together should be something like:

```
def largestState():
    INPUT = "statepopulations.csv"
    COLUMN = 5
    with open(INPUT, "rU") as csvFile:
        data = csv.reader(csvFile)
        next(data, None)
    return max(data, key=lambda _: _[COLUMN])
```

Comment: I plugged in your code and still have no luck, now I'm developing errors with "line containing NULL bytes". Google says its a problem with my csv, and I'm not sure how to work around this, as my professor will be grading with this exact file. Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like another question